# Awkward line wrap around image

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, responsive-design

Probably easiest to explain what I'm after with an image:

[image]

When I float an image the text runs around it which is great. BUT, depending on the amount of text and the image size, I'm often left with these awkward bits. In this case the awkward text would look better in the column next to the image.

I *could* add more bottom margin to the image depending on how much awkward text there is BUT in a responsive design the image shrinks and the text stays the same size so there is no way of doing this for every image at every break point.

I *could* use "overflow:auto" on all paragraphs so that it creates a new layout context and stops the text from wrapping altogether. BUT I want the text to float when there is enough text and again I don't get control over the final output.

I have a feeling that unless there's some overly complicated JS that can run on this (and can handle the screen size changing on a responsive site) there is no solution. So my question would be how do people handle this? Ignore it? Use JS?

Thanks

Comment: I usually just plan the layout before and use grids to avoid these type of issues, but sometimes when you can't avoid it I just let it be...

Comment: do you want it to not wrap only when there is a small amount of text or always not wrap?

Comment: Personally, I'd leave it be; if only because it's hard to predictably/reliably define the amount of text that would qualify as 'an awkward bit.'

Comment: @liam - it depends really. In the example above it shouldn't wrap but it should if there was two lines really.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this in CSS.  However, I don't think the JavaScript would be overly complicated either.  I'd recommend using [`element.getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getClientRects), which returns a list of  TextRectangle objects.  For inline elements, each TextRectangle object represents a line of text.

If you check that the left offset of the last TextRectangle is different to the left offset of the penultimate TextRectangle, you know that the last line is a "straggler" and can adjust the image's bottom margin by the height of one TextRectangle (`bottom - top`).

`getClientRects` was standardised in CSSOM, but [may have buggy implementations](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t22) in some browsers.

From a more personal point of view, I'd say that I think it looks fine the way it is and I probably wouldn't worry about it if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for this. It gives me something to go on. I have generally been ignoring it but its starting to annoy me now. - I know I need to give up some control but at the same time I'm trying to make the websites look the best that they can at all screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this is to add another DIV around your text and float that left as well.

So your html would end up like:

```
<div>
    <img src="">
    <div>
        My text...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe he wants the wrapping effect if there is more text.