# Prevent single word from wrapping around float in css/html

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

Is there any way to prevent a single word or two from wrapping around a float, but allow it if there is more text? Here is an example where the first text is problematic, but the second text is fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdPCp/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals" />
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <span class="last-bit">labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</span></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals" />
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="last-text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.text {
}

.last-text {
}
```

Update: Note that I don't know in advance where the text will wrap - I'm looking for a general solution, if it exists. For example, some style for ".last-text" that causes it to not wrap under a float.

CSS/HTML solutions are preferable over JavaScript.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the first bit of text? Rather, what would you like it to look like?

Comment: The last word wraps underneath the image, and doesn't appear to be connected to the rest of the text. Basically if it's just a few words I'd like to wrap directly under the text, and otherwise have it wrap under the floated element as normal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Preventing single-word wrapping is easy: just use a no-break space between the last two words, instead of a normal space (e.g., `nostrud&nbsp;exercitation`).

However, I’m afraid this would not solve the real problem. In the sample case, there would be a two-word wrap, leaving the last but one line short. And if text gets larger, the two words would stick together even when there is no need for that.

I’m afraid that problem would need some nontrivial JavaScript code that analyzes, after initial formatting, the height of the text block as compared with the height of the image and changes styling by some criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `padding-bottom: 1px;` to `img`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdPCp/1/)

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

You can also use right and left columns, yeah I've certainly used an inline style but if you want to go for this approach than make a class for clear and get rid of the inline style

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdPCp/5/)

Comment: That works in this particular case, but I don't know in advance where the text will wrap (i.e., this is in a template and the text could be any length). I'm looking for a more general solution if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - not a definite answer but I asked the same question a while back. One of the answers I received there was promising (using JS) but so far I haven't been able to work it out. My question also uses an image to illustrate the issue which might be helpful.

I come across this issue all the time in responsive layouts using a CMS

[Awkward line wrap around image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811049/awkward-line-wrap-around-image)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to increase the `.wrapper` class width a little.

here is the `.wrapper` class:

```
.wrapper {
        width:330px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdPCp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.text` if you don't want the text to wrap under the float.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdPCp/6/

Comment: I *do* want it to wrap if there's more than a few words. The "last-text" span is there because I was trying overflow:hidden on it, but that trick doesn't work on inline elements apparently.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to ask. The default behavior of text put after a floated element is to wrap around the floated element.

Comment: Sure - but as your example shows, text can be styled to not wrap around the element. I was wondering if there was a way to only prevent the last bit of text from not wrapping around it. But it doesn't look that way (without javascript).

Comment: So you're saying that if there's only one line of text wrapping around the image, it shouldn't wrap, but if there's more than one line of text wrapping around the image, then it should wrap?

Answer (score 0):

Look through the different display styles.  Table display (not the tags) do not under-wrap floated elements.

```
.text{
  display:table;
}
```