# Prevent single Chinese character from wrapping around the floating image?

Tags: html, css

> [Prevent single word from wrapping around float in css/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883495/prevent-single-word-from-wrapping-around-float-in-css-html)

I have read the above question but it only works on English. How to prevent one single Chinese character from wrapping around the floating image when the gap width between image and border is only enough to accommodate one Chinese character?

https://jsfiddle.net/njsy1037/

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DSUG7rl.jpg">
    這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。
</div>
<div id="b">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DSUG7rl.jpg">
    這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。這是關於柴犬Coco的簡介，可以多寫一些關於柴犬Coco的簡介。
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}

#a {
    width: 100%;
}

#a:before {
    content: '';
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}

img {
    float: right;
    width: 178px;
    height: 180px;
}

#b {
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[image: How to prevent one single Chinese character from wrapping around the floating image?]